# SYMFONY Hydrate file type for updating instance

Tags: php, symfony

Hi everybody I'm working onn a new project with Symfony and i have some difficulties with the edit views when they have an input file, when i open edit view for un product i have the name input hydrated with the name of product, the input price with the price of product but the photo input file empty :s

How can i do to hydarat this input file before the persist of the modification

My FormBuilder

```html
class ProductEditType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name',TextType::class)
        ->add('price',TextType::class)
        ->add('Photo',PhotoType::class)
        ->add('enregistrer',SubmitType::class);
    }
```

the controller

```html
public function editProductAction($id, Request $request){
        $product = new Product();
        $repository=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyProjectProductBundle:Product');
        $product= $repository->find($id);
        $form=$this->get('form.factory')->create(ProductEditType::class,$product);
        if($request->isMethod('post') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()){

            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('my_project_backoffice_product', array('id'=>$product->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('MyProjectBackofficeBundle:Backoffice:editproduct.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView(),'product'=>$product));

    }
```

PhotoType

```html
class PhotoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', FileType::class)     ;
    }
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyProject\ProductBundle\Entity\Photo'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'myproject_productbundle_photo';
    }
```

twig view

```html
<div class="well">

   {{ form_start(form) }}
 

<div class="container4_in">
 <div class="gri4">
  <div class="grid2">
  <div class="form_elem_wrraper">

    <div class="row_form">
    {{ form_label(form.name, "Name ") }}
    {# Génération de l'input. #}
    {{ form_widget(form.name,{ 'attr': {'class' :'input', 'placeholder': "Entrez le nom de l'auteur"}}) }}
    </div>

    
</div></div>



<div class="grid2">
  <div class="form_elem_wrraper">

   <div class="row_form">
    {{ form_label(form.price, "Price ") }}
    {# Génération de l'input. #}
    {{ form_widget(form.price,{ 'attr': {'class' :'input', 'placeholder': "Entrez le nom de l'auteur"}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row_form">
    {{ form_label(form.Photo, "Photo") }}
    {# Génération de l'input. #}
    {{ form_widget(form.Photo) }}
    </div>

    

</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>

  {# Pour le bouton, pas de label ni d'erreur, on affiche juste le widget #}
  {{ form_widget(form.enregistrer,{'attr': {'class': 'btn_bleu btn_submit_form'}}) }}

  {# Fermeture de la balise <form> du formulaire HTML #}
  {{ form_end(form) }}

        
       </form>
```

I need your help, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's file form types are not propagated with data from backend. If you would like to show existing file, you have to add it manually in your Twig file.

As you didn't attached your entity code, please note that my example should be used with proper methods from your `MyProject\ProductBundle\Entity\Photo` class.

In my example you have to pass to the view Photo entity as `photo`, but only if there was already uploaded file before.

```
<div class="row_form">
    {% if photo is defined %}
        Current photo: <img src="{{ photo.getWebPath() }}" />
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_label(form.Photo, "Photo") }}
    {# Génération de l'input. #}
    {{ form_widget(form.Photo) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Please improve your comment, because it's not understandable.

Comment: Ok sorry, i have an form for updating the informations of the product who is already saved in the database, in the twig view i must have the input name completed with the name of product and the input file completed with product's photo. In your exemple i don't really understand if this solution gonna resolve my problem, i think i will have always the input file empty

Comment: Yes, file input will be always empty. What is the reason to have this input filled? You should not need it.

Comment: Im in the update view i need complet the inputs before the form call in the controller, i need have the inputs completed with their values from the database

Comment: I understand basics of update screen. I just don't understand why are you sticked to propagation of file input?

Comment: In the update or the edit view, you must have the inputs already completed with their values from the database, cause if you click save without changes you reserve the same values, and you change some values the database will be updated

Comment: You can't propagate input fields. In your controller logic, you have to predict if file input was uploaded. Check this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html#using-a-doctrine-listener
On line 43 there is code `if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) return;`. This basic construction combined with rest of best Symfony procedures saves you from setting file to NULL on update.